# Global variable in stateless WebApi Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api

This morning I asked myself a very important question about a stateless C# ASP.NET WebApi Controller : 
As my application is hosted in the cloud, I wonder if it's reliable to create a global variable inside the Controller.
Here is an exemple :

```
 private readonly UserService _userService;
     private readonly TechniqService _techniqService;

    // global variable
    private readonly string _userRole;

     public BuildingController(IMapper mapper, UserService userService, TechniqService techniqService)
     {

         _userService = userService;
         _techniqService = techniqService;

        // is it ok to define this variable like this?
        var userId = GetUserId();// this fetch the userId from a token sent with each request
        _userRole = _userService.GetUserRoleFromId(userId);
     }
```

Points for YES:

- A controller **might be** (which means, i'm not sure) instanciated every time you call a method inside your api, so here, your user will be retrieved properly everytime

Points for NO:

- The controller HAS TO BE stateless, which means that if you call your api twice in a row, you can't rely on the fact that your variable will still exist.

Any explanations on this?
Thank you.

Comment: I dont see _userRole is a global variable

Comment: Ok, _userRole is "global" for all the controller's method beneath.
But still, this variable will be defined for every request, so... where's the trouble? @PeterBons

Comment: Per my understanding, your `_userRole` is just an instance field. If the user role does not change frequently, I assumed that you could set the value when constructing your apicontroller instance and share the same value among all methods within your controller. Or you could define a property named UserRole and return the userrole via `_userService.GetUserRoleFromId` every time.